# Unable to push image to OpenShift internal registry with i/o timeout

Tags: azure, docker, openshift

```
Pushing image docker-registry.default.svc:5000/th/th:source ...
Warning: Push failed, retrying in 5s ...
Warning: Push failed, retrying in 5s ...
Warning: Push failed, retrying in 5s ...
Warning: Push failed, retrying in 5s ...
Warning: Push failed, retrying in 5s ...
Warning: Push failed, retrying in 5s ...
Warning: Push failed, retrying in 5s ...
Registry server Address: 
Registry server User Name: serviceaccount
Registry server Email: serviceaccount@example.org
Registry server Password: <<non-empty>>
error: build error: Failed to push image: After retrying 6 times, Push image still failed due to error: Get https://docker-registry.default.svc:5000/v1/_ping:  dial TCP<ip>:5000: i/o timeout
```

Manually pushing an image from the CLI to the internal registry is working fine.

I have deployed the OpenShift instance 3.11 on a couple of azure VMs, while deploying I took care of adding external IP to the same.

All other images are also present in the docker registry and the curl command to the docker registry returns with exit code 0

What seemed curious was while deploying my app I tried pinging the registry from the build pods terminal. This resulted in the connection being hung up and no response.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: please add the curl command with output to the problematic registry in question

Comment: `[root@node-okd ]# curl -kv  docker-registry.default.svc:5000
* About to connect() to docker-registry.default.svc port 5000 (#0)
* Trying <ip>...`

This is the only output generated by the compute node. The curl command works fine on the master node.
`[root@master-okd deploy]# curl  docker-registry.default.svc:5000
`

Comment: You are trying to connect using the k8s inner cluster network domain system from a VM rather than a pod, that shouldn't, wouldn't and doesn't work. You need to expose the service for the registry using a route or if doesn't work over http with nodeport or externalIP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sdn was causing this networking issue.

> Does Azure support Calico networking?
>
> Calico in VXLAN mode is supported on Azure. However, IPIP packets are
> blocked by the Azure network fabric.

The above quote from [calico reference](https://projectcalico.docs.tigera.io/reference/public-cloud/azure) was the reason this issue was caused. This could be resolved by changing to VXLAN mode in calico config. More details on how to switch can be found [here](https://docs.projectcalico.org/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/config-options#switching-from-ip-in-ip-to-vxlan).

For my solution I just switched to the default openshift sdn 'ovs-subnet' from calico in the inventory file.